Tilemaker output file is not appearing
I tried using Tilemaker to convert a map in .osm.pbf format (from Geofabrik) into an .mbtiles map, but I can’t manage to get an output file.
I downloaded the zip file from GitHub and renamed the config-example and process-example files to just config and process. Then I ran Tilemaker and the command prompt as administrator and provided all the full paths (for the input, output, config, and process files). However, no matter what I do, my output file just doesn’t appear anywhere. I’ve even downloaded the map multiple times, and the process doesn’t show any errors.
cmd
tilemaker --input C:\TileMaker\germany-latest.osm.pbf --output C:\TileMaker\germany.mbtiles

the output is:
Layer poi (z12-14)
Layer transportation (z4-14)
Layer transportation_name (z10-14)
Layer building (z13-14)
Layer water (z6-14)
Layer waterway (z6-14)
Bounding box 6.38588, 51.4797, 8.32118, 52.5524

